# How should the return uri be encoded in google auth request?

Tags: node.js, google-authentication

I'm trying to implement a small app using the google auth API, but I'm basically stuck on the first step. All of my code is below:

```
var google = require("googleapis");
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const encodedUrl = 
encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:3000/oauthcallback");
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    "YOU CAN'T SEE THIS",
    "THIS IS ALSO SECRET",
    encodedUrl
);
const getLoginUrl = () => {
    const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
        access_type: "offline",

        // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
        scope: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
        ]
    });
    return url;
};

let url = getLoginUrl();
url;
```

The plan for this code was that it should give me the code I need to authenticate, and it does, but it doesn't work. For some reason I get:

> Error: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Uri must consist of printable > ASCII characters: http://localhost:3000/oauthcallback​​​​​

Any ideas? I have tried both to url encode and not using `encodeURIComponent`, but with the same result for both scenarios.